# Reuse output of two MapReduce jobs and join the results together

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to join the output of two different MapReduce jobs. I want to be able to do something like I have below, but I cannot figure out how to reuse results from previous jobs and join them. How could I do this?

```
Job1: 
Andrea Vanzo, c288f70f-f417-4a96-8528-25c61372cae7, 125 

Job2:
c288f70f-f417-4a96-8528-25c61372cae7, 071e1103-1b06-4671-8324-a9beb3e90d18, 25

Result:
Andrea Vanzo, c288f70f-f417-4a96-8528-25c61372cae7,  25
```

Comment: use `hadoop fs -getmerge` commands

Comment: also read this blog http://rare-chiller-615.appspot.com/mr2.html ..

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JobControl`  to  set  your workflow in your mappereduce ,BTW  read job1&job2 's output (use  `MultipleInputs`) also  could solved your problem .

Use different processing methods and write data according to the path of the data.

mapper

job1data == job1.path = >  split  write key data[1] ,value data[0]+"tagjob1"

job2data ==job2.path = >split  write key data[0] ,value data[0]+"tagjob2"

reducer
each key has it value sets .

put  the values into two list  group by  your "tag"

write  the key and  each Cartesian product  of the two list .

hopes